# Separate Notifications do not appear on a same device subscribed to a topic

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

when i push multiple notifications in a loop via api subscribed to topic using FCM, the previous notification replaced by new notification on my android device. Is there a way to push multiple notifications separately. I am using PHP Curl request.

```
foreach ($result as $item)
{
                    $message = array
                    (
                        'body' => "Details:".$item['tagid'],
                        'title' => "Tag:".$item['event'],
                        'key1' => "NotificationActivity"
                    );

                    $fields = array(
                        'to' => '/topics/all',
                        'data' => array
                        (
                            'message' => $message
                        ),
                    );
                    $headers = array
                    (
                        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was problem on my Firebase service. Not identifying notification on id basis.
Problem was, I was passing 0 in id field.
`notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());`

After setting unique id of each notification, it's working:

```
notificationManager.notify(id /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```